# Python can't load libc when importing xfsm module

Tags: python, libc

I'm trying to write Python code to manipulate Xerox FST files, and I've installed the Python bindings for libxfsm and the XFSM library available through http://fsmbook.com. I'm running 64-bit Ubuntu. The installation goes fine, but when I try to import the xfsm module, I get this error:

```
>>> import xfsm
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xfsm/__init__.py", line
 30, in <module>
    import xfsm.errors # So error handler gets installed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xfsm/errors.py", line
 8, in <module>
    from xfsm.utils import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xfsm/utils.py", line
 39, in <module>
    libc = cfsm.load_library("c")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xfsm/cfsm_api.py", line
 366, in l                 oad_library
    raise ImportError("%s not found." % libname)
 ImportError: c not found.
```

Inspecting the source code for the Python interface, it looks like it is trying and failing to find libc, and failing, but I am at a loss on how to fix that.

Has anybody else gotten the Python-XFST interface working, or have any idea what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem on **64-bit Ubuntu 14.04**. The problem is it can't find **libc**. In my case **libc** on my OS is name **libc.so.6**(I don't know why, I am new on Ubuntu). But the Python-XFST doesn't recognize it (Detail your can refer to source file)

My solution is simple, just modify **xfsm/utils.py** file in

```
**Line 39** : libc = cfsm.load_library("c")
```

to

```
**Line 39** : libc = cfsm.load_library("libc.so.6")
```

Remember to add the path to **libc.so.6** in **env**.